# Printing double sided static window cling

Tags: print-design, print-production

I need a double sided banner placed on a storefront window.
Preferably a static window cling, but if that's not possible, a sticker paper.
I am not looking for a mirrored design. There is text printed on it, which needs to be read from both sides, so a transparent print is not going to work.

Is there a way to print such a thing at home on a color inkjet?
Any pointers on how to achieve this at home with a printer will be greatly appreciated. Links to products I need to buy to print on will be amazing.

Comment: I don't believe double-sided *and* sticky exists. It's one or the other, never both. Unless, you print on something then use spray adhesive to make it sticky.

Comment: Just imagine what an adhesive surface would do to print heads.....

Comment: Inkjet inks will fade within a week if placed in a window. Longer than that and it will become quite obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a printer that can print with White Ink.
the printer will print reversed (so it is right reading through media)
A white layer, then print the CMYK part again, but right reading (from the front of media).

Otherwise you can print 2 different pieces and mount them together to form a 2 sided window decal.

Comment: Indeed, I ended up printing one transparent decal and one white background to stick on top of it, and then stick the whole thing on the window. My problem now is that the color from transparent decal shines through to the sticker paper so it looks bad. I am thinking perhaps I should print on premium vinyl which will let nothing through? Will this work? https://www.amazon.com/Printable-Vinyl-Sticker-Paper-Self-Adhesive/dp/B07T83CSCG

Answer (score 0):

Go to office depot or staples and have them print you a small yard sign like material and hang it to you window using suction cups.
or buy a white 11x8.5 inkjet printer label and print your design and get a foam board and stick it to that.